# Populate data into listview using json parsom with restful api

Tags: android, json

I have to run json format which is shown in below 
and have to parse this data into listview[image]

and for this i tried following code

MainActivity

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                            SyncMethod("http://52.26.35.210/api/web/v1/api-beautician/country-state-city");



                                    }
                                }
        );

        notification_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                String postloadid = actorsList.get(position).gettitle();
                String source_addoc=actorsList.get(position).gettitle();
                Constants.vCountry=actorsList.get(position).gettitle();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selecting "+ Constants.vCountry+" State ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    public void init()
    {


        norecord=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.norecord);

        notification_listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_notification);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh()
    {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            SyncMethod("http://52.26.35.210/api/web/v1/api-beautician/country-state-city");




    }
    private static String pad(int c)
    {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            SyncMethod("http://52.26.35.210/api/web/v1/api-beautician/country-state-city");



    }
    public void SyncMethod(final String GetUrl)
    {

        Log.i("Url.............", GetUrl);
        final Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            // After call for background.start this run method call
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String url = GetUrl;
                    String SetServerString = "";
                    // document all_stuff = null;

                    SetServerString = fetchResult(url);
                    threadMsg(SetServerString);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("Animation", "Thread  exception " + t);
                }
            }

            private void threadMsg(String msg) {

                if (!msg.equals(null) && !msg.equals("")) {
                    Message msgObj = handler11.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("message", msg);
                    msgObj.setData(b);
                    handler11.sendMessage(msgObj);
                }
            }

            // Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and update the progress
            private final Handler handler11 = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    try {
                        String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");
                        Log.e("Exam", "screen>>" + aResponse);

                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(aResponse);
                        Log.e("Home Get draft--", jobj.toString());
                        String status = jobj.getString("status");

                        Log.e("Myorder Homestatusdraft",status);
                        Log.e("--------------------", "----------------------------------");
                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                        {
                            actorsList = new ArrayList<Doctortype_method>();
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                            array = jobj.getJSONArray("response");
                            if(actorsList.size()>0){
                                actorsList.clear();
                            }
                            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                            {

                                JSONObject jsonChildNode = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                actorsList.add(new Doctortype_method(jsonChildNode.optString("State id"),jsonChildNode.optString("State name")));

                            }
                            if (getApplicationContext() != null)
                            {

                                if (adapter == null)
                                {
                                    adapter = new Doctortype_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),actorsList);
                                    notification_listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                                } else {
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                            if(actorsList.size()==0)
                            {
                                norecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            norecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            // UF.msg(message + "");
                        }



                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }


                }
            };
        });
        // Start Thread
        background.start();
    }

    public String fetchResult(String urlString) throws JSONException {
        StringBuilder builder;
        BufferedReader reader;
        URLConnection connection = null;
        URL url = null;
        String line;
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = url.openConnection();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            //Log.d("DATA", builder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        //JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(builder.toString());
        return builder.toString();

}
}
```

For this i also add adapter as well as arraylist.
but when i run this application api is not called perfectly..
hope anyone a]can help me..

here i add adapter and arraylist

Adapter

```
public Doctortype_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Doctortype_method> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_doctortype, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.actorList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        //View v = convertView;
        View rowView;
        ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {

            rowView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_doctortype, null);
            setViewHolder(rowView);
        } else {
            rowView = convertView;

        }
        vh = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        vh.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(actorList.get(position).gettitle()));
        vh.subtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(actorList.get(position).getsubtitle()));


       /* String image=actorList.get(position).getid();
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(vh.dimage, image.toString(), R.drawable.no_img);*/

        return rowView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView title, subtitle;

    }

    private void setViewHolder(View rowView) {
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();

        vh.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
        vh.subtitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);

}
}
```

arraylist

```
public Doctortype_method( String title, String subtitle) {
        super();
        this.title = title;

        this.subtitle = subtitle;

    }


    public String gettitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void settitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getsubtitle()
    {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public void setsubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }
```

there is no error but when i run this code api is not called and i didnt get the output i want.
Thnx in advance..

Comment: Try to use GSON library (https://github.com/google/gson) instead manual JSON parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the right answer.
May anyone get help from this in future.

ActivityClass.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_city_list_item);


        lv_city = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_city);

        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        city_stateid = b.getString("stateid");
        city_statename=b.getString("stateName");
        city_countryid=b.getString("country");


        lv_city.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                page_cityname  = cityist.get(position).getCityName();

                SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("abc",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sp.edit();
                edit.putString("city_name", page_cityname);
                edit.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected city & State"+page_cityname + "-" +city_statename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
                /*i.putExtra("cityname", page_cityname);*/
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        params12 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", city_type));
        params12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stateID", city_stateid));
        params12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryID", city_countryid));

        new Sync().execute();


    }


    class Sync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String obj;//new JSONArray();
            try {
                // obj=getJSONFromUrl("Your posting path", params11);
                obj = getJSONFromUrl("http://52.26.35.210/api/web/v1/api-beautician/country-state-city", params12);
                return obj;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.e("Result of geting data", "" + result);
            try {

                Log.e("Exam", "screen>>" + result);
                JSONObject get_res = new JSONObject(result);
                String status = get_res.getString("status");
                Log.e("Exam", "screen33333>>" + status);
                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    cityist = new ArrayList<city_method>();
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                    array = get_res.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        cityist.add(new city_method(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("cityID"),array.getJSONObject(i).getString("cityName")));



                    }
                    if (getApplicationContext() != null)
                    {

                        if (adapter == null)
                        {
                            adapter = new city_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),cityist);
                            lv_city.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } else {
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
    }

    public String fetchResult(String urlString) throws JSONException {
        StringBuilder builder;
        BufferedReader reader;
        URLConnection connection = null;
        URL url = null;
        String line;
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = url.openConnection();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            //Log.d("DATA", builder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        //JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(builder.toString());
        return builder.toString();
    }


    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String json = "";

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                //sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return json;

    }
}
```

Adapterclass.java

```
public class city_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<city_method> {
    ArrayList<city_method> citylist;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    Context context;

    public city_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<city_method> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_doctortype, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.citylist = items;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        //View v = convertView;
        View rowView;
        city_Adapter.ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {

            rowView = vi.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
            setViewHolder(rowView);
        } else {
            rowView = convertView;

        }
        vh = (city_Adapter.ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        vh.cityid.setText((citylist.get(position).getCityID()));
        vh.cityname.setText((citylist.get(position).getCityName()));




        return rowView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {


        private TextView cityid,cityname;

    }

    private void setViewHolder(View rowView) {
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();

        vh.cityid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cityid);
        vh.cityname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cityname);

        rowView.setTag(vh);
    }
}
```

Methodclass.java

```
public class city_method {

    private String cityID,cityName;

    public String getCityID() {
        return cityID;
    }

    public void setCityID(String cityID) {
        this.cityID = cityID;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public city_method(String cityID, String cityName) {
        this.cityID = cityID;
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))` is wrong because you getting `status:1` so it is `if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))` try this and then change this `array = jobj.getJSONArray("response");` to `array = jobj.getJSONArray("data");` your JSONArray key is `"data"`

And replace this also

```
actorsList.add(new Doctortype_method(jsonChildNode.optString("State id"),jsonChildNode.optString("State name")));
```

with

```
actorsList.add(new Doctortype_method(jsonChildNode.optString("countryID"),jsonChildNode.optString("vCountry")));
```

hope this helps. if this doesn't help feel free to ask

EDIT:

I cant understand what you want but have a look at this 
-> you need to create baseAdapter for listview and set that adapter into the listview with your arraylist

FOR FETCHING YOUR ABOVE DATA YOU NEED TO DO BELOW CODE:

```
String data;//your entire JSON data as String
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
        String status = object.getString("status");
        JSONArray dataArray = object.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject json1 = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String countryID = json1.getString("countryID");
          String vCountry = json1.getString("vCountry");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now if you want to show this vCountry in listview you have to add vCountry in ArrayList and then in listview.setAdapter you have to pass this ArrayList which is filled by vCountry. Hope you understand now. If you want adapter and listview code please check this link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: actually here i have to pass parameter type=country to fetch result but i dont to how to code for that.

Comment: means what you want i cant understand properly bro. please describe so i can help you

Comment: in this api i have a parameter name "type=country" and then  i get the output as shown in figure.that thing i have to fetch in listview.

Comment: so you got type = country right? or there is a problem in it? what you need? you just need how to parse your above image data in android? or you need anything else?

Comment: i need that data in listview

Comment: you need vCountry & countryID in listview?